# BigSur - Location of plist for Finder Sidebar

Tags: finder

This seems to have been moved in bigsur. It used to be located in:
~/Library/Preferences/sidebarlists.plist

Im trying to back up my finder sidebar configuration. Copy and Pasting this plist file from Mac install to Mac install used to be the way.

Comment: I suspect that it is no longer in a plist.

Answer (score 3):

According to

https://community.jamf.com/t5/jamf-pro/managing-finder-sidebar-items-on-highsierra/m-p/207140

the file is

~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.FavoriteItems.sfl

I have confirmed by deleting this and relaunching the Finder. The Finder creates a new blank, presumably from the User Template.